# Merge Array on the basis of same key and value Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have two array, with common key and value i.e. 'id'

```
        $arr_1 = [
           '0'=>[
                  id=1,
                  name='Foo'
                ]
           '1'=>[
                  id=2,
                  name='Bar'
                ]
         ];

        $arr_2 = [
           '0'=>[
                  id=1,
                  Percentage=60
                ]
           '1'=>[
                  id=2,
                  Percentage=70
                ]
         ]
```

i want to combine it, to form a new array, based on common key and value

The result should be,

```
        $arr_3 = [
           '0'=>[
                  id=1,
                  name='Foo'
                  Percentage=60
                ]
           '1'=>[
                  id=2,
                  name='Bar'
                  Percentage=70
                ]
         ];
```

Comment: foreach($arr_1 as $key => $arr1){
                foreach($arr_2 as $arr2){
                        if($arr1['id'] == $arr2['id']){
                                $arr_1[$key]['Percentage'] = $arr2['Percentage'] ;
                        }
                }
      }

Answer (score 0):

With two arrays

```
  $arr_1 = collect(array(
      '0' => array(
              'id' => 1,
              'name' =>'Foo'
      ),
      '1' => array(
              'id'=> 2,
              'name'=> 'Bar'
        ),
   ));

  $arr_2 = collect(array(
      '0'=>array(
            'id'=> 1,
            'Percentage'=> 60
      ),
      '1'=>array(
            'id'=> 2,
            'Percentage'=> 70
      )
  ));
```

In your controller

```
$arr_3 = $arr_1->map(function($row) use ($arr_2) {
    $percent = $arr_2->where('id', $row['id'])->pluck('Percentage');
    return collect($row)->put('NewPercent', $percent);
});
```

Backtesting

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Foo","NewPercent":[60]},
    {"id":2,"name":"Bar","NewPercent":[70]}
]
```

Edit 1:

For only the value:

```
  $arr_3 = $arr_1->map(function($row, $key) use ($arr_2) {
    
    $currentArr = $arr_2->where('id', $row['id'])->first();
    $percent = Arr::get($currentArr, 'Percentage');
    return collect($row)->put('Percentage', $percent);
  });
```

Testing:

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Foo","Percentage":60},
    {"id":2,"name":"Bar","Percentage":70}
]
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help. 
The above code makes NewPercentage as an array, which should not be.

Comment: @ShahzadaIqbal, check my edit